# Regular expression replacing only if contained withing a regular expression match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following:

```
[list]
[*] test
[*] test
[*] test
[/list]
```

and I would like to create a regular expression that turns that into:

```
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
```

I know regex enough to replace simple tags, but in this case I need to replace li tags only if they are contained inside ul. Is there a way to check that before replacing?

I am using JavaScript if that matters.

Comment: A proper parser is needed here, this is not a job for regex.

Comment: @gregmac, you don't know that. If the lists are not nested, and nothing else than those list-thingies need to be replaced as a one time action, then regex is fine. But, if a broader set of structures need to be replaced, or the language can get a recursive nature, then you're right. But as of now, there's too little information to make that judgement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the text:

```
[*] test1

[list]
[*] test2
[*] test3
[*] test4
[/list]

[*] test5
```

the regex:

```
\[\*]\s*([^\r\n]+)(?=((?!\[list])[\s\S])*\[/list])
```

matches only `[*] test2`, `[*] test3` and `[*] test4`. But if the `[list]`'s can be nested, or a more broader set of a BB-like language needs to be parsed, I opt for a proper parser.

To do the replacements, replace the regex I suggested with:

```
<li>$1</li>
```

and then replace `[list]` with `<ul>` and `[/list]` with `</ul>` (assuming `[list]` and `[/list]` are only used for lists and are not present in comments or string literals or something).

When [running the following snippet](http://ideone.com/JkLOg):

```
var text = "[*] test1\n"+
    "\n"+
    "[list]\n"+
    "[*] test2\n"+
    "[*] test3\n"+
    "[*] test4\n"+
    "[/list]\n"+
    "\n"+
    "[*] test5\n"+
    "\n"+
    "[list]\n"+
    "[*] test6\n"+
    "[*] test7\n"+
    "[/list]\n"+
    "\n"+
    "[*] test8";

print(text + "\n============================");
text = text.replace(/\[\*]\s*([^\r\n]+)(?=((?!\[list])[\s\S])*\[\/list])/g, "<li>$1</li>");
text = text.replace(/\[list]/g, "<ul>");
text = text.replace(/\[\/list]/g, "</ul>");
print(text);
```

the following is printed:

```
[*] test1

[list]
[*] test2
[*] test3
[*] test4
[/list]

[*] test5

[list]
[*] test6
[*] test7
[/list]

[*] test8
============================
[*] test1

<ul>
<li>test2</li>
<li>test3</li>
<li>test4</li>
</ul>

[*] test5

<ul>
<li>test6</li>
<li>test7</li>
</ul>

[*] test8
```

A small explanation might be in order:

- `\[\*]\s*` matches the sub string `[*]` followed by zero or more white space characters;
- `([^\r\n]+)` gobbles up the rest of the line and saves it in match group 1;
- `(?=((?!\[list])[\s\S])*\[/list])` ensures that every match group 1 must have a sub string `[/list]` ahead of **without** encoutering a `[list]`

**EDIT**

Or better yet, do as Gumbo suggest in the comment to this answer: match all `[list] ... [/list]` and then replace all `[*] ...` in those.

Comment: You should do a more systematical approach: Search for every `[list] … [/list]` and for every match replace every occurrence of `[*]` in it.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a better approach to Bart K.’s suggestion:

- find all `[list] … [/list]`
- for each match, find all `[*]` in it

This will ensure that only `[*]` in `[list] … [/list]` will be replaced.

The code:

```
str.replace(/\[list]([\s\S]*?)\[\/list]/g, function($0, $1) {
    return "<ul>" + $1.replace(/^ *\[\*] *(.*)/gm, "<li>$1</li>") + "</ul>";
})
```